# How to form an indentation in wood to hold candles?

Tags: cutting

I want to make indentations to hold votive candles in a decorative piece of wood. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What is the diameter of the candles you're using?

Comment: In addition to the above what thickness of wood will you be making the holes in? And does it matter if you make a hole in the back of the wood? To give good recommendations it would also be useful to know what drill(s) you have available, as if the candles are of fairly large diameter Forstner bits (and the similar sawtooth bit) may be the best choice, but they work better and more safely in a drill press/bench drill, or in a handheld electric drill mounted in a drill stand.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to a Forstner bit, this can be done with a router and template. The choice probably depends on how many you're making and what power tools you have available. Depending on how deep the hole is, a "trim" or "pony" router would likely do the job.

Considerations would include:

- Availability of a drill press (a forstner bit might not do a great job in a hand drill)
- Cost and number of holes you can get out of a forstner bit of the right size.
- Hole size of close-enough size being available as a standard forstner bit.
- One-off versus production (dozens or hundreds) scale.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a flat-bottomed hole the best tool to use will be a forstner drill bit.  You'll probably want to use a drill press to ensure the holes are straight.